# Can't access harddrive

Tags: permissions, hard-drive

I installed Kubuntu onto an MSI gaming laptop. Which has two drives, 128GB SSD and 1TB HD. The OS and boot drive is on the SSD and works fine. I used KDE Partition Manager to format and mount the HDD with the ext4 filesystem at the mount point `/home/joe/Data` and the partition is `/dev/sdb1`. A lock symbol appears next to the mount point.

I can't write to or read from this drive. Properties show owner as root, but I have no way of accessing this. Is there an easy way to make this available as a read/write drive to store my data? The laptop is personal, so I have no fears of who gets access.

Answer (score 0):

Update in case it helps others. This worked for me:

```
$ sudo chmod -R a+rwX /home/joe/Data
```

Comment: The `a+` will add the permissions for all users which, judging by `/home/joe/Data` that appears to be part of a certain user's home directory, might be a very bad idea ... You can use `u+` instead to add permissions to the current user.

Comment: This ^^^ makes a lot more sense.